# Fourier exponential series of odd functions does not have even coefficients?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Consider the exponential fourier series

$$
f(t)= \sum\limits_{n =  - \infty }^\infty  {c_n e^{i n\omega _0 t} } $$

if $f$ is odd $f(-t)=-f(t)$, then how is this visible in the series? Are there only the odd $n$ values? i.e. $c_n=0$ for even $n$?

Comment: If $f(t)$ is real and odd, then its Fourier Series will be purely imaginary and odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case,$$f(-t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_n e^{-i\omega_0nt}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_{-n} e^{i\omega_0nt}\\-f(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}-c_n e^{i\omega_0nt}$$which leads to$$c_{-n}=-c_n$$therefore **also $c_n$ is odd** and we can write$$f(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2i c_n \sin n\omega_0 t$$